Automatic sync of selected files in a monorepo to separate repos
I am failing to set up an Actions workflow to run upon a push to a monorepo and sync files to target repos in the same account. It is supposed to read JSON from a GitHub variable which defines the target repos and their respective files that should be synced from the monorepo, if they have changed:
[
    {
  "repo1": {
    "repo": "account/repo1",
    "include": [
      "index.js",
      "somefile.js" 
    ]
  },
  "repo2": {
    "repo": "account/repo2",
    "include": [
      "start.js",
      "otherfile.js" 
    ]
  }
]

I have tried various versions of workflow YAML, none is better than the others, they all give errors.

What did you try so far?
